# Erro Can't convert to color: type=0x2

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin

No xamarin, ao debugar a aplicação, aparece esse erro

> Can't convert to color: type=0x2

no método `SetSupportActionBar(...);`

**Trecho:**

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar myToolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
try
{
    SetSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

**Erro:**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:937)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:871)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:867)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:599)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:266)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:77)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
    at md502421d8729da12f55310be49821813f4.NewMainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md502421d8729da12f55310be49821813f4.NewMainActivity.onCreate(NewMainActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Veja aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986204/cant-convert-to-color-type-0x2-error-when-inflating-layout-in-fragment-but-onl

Comment: Eu já tinha visto isso, mas não me ajudou...